# Product set to active randomly

Tags: magento-1.9

I get a weird error. Suddenly alot of inactive products are now visible in the front end without anyone doing changing anything. Do you have any idea how it can happen. We do CRON jobs that do re-index 4 times a day. But I don't see how that can be the reason.

I am using multi stores (english & danish) and the products are set to "inactive" for both store views.